# Save response body to file when "check" fail in k6

Tags: javascript, load-testing, k6

Is there any way for `k6` to save every response body and response code of the failed checks/assertion?

maybe something like

```
check(res, {"rc code": (r) => r.status == rc_code,}) || AppendErrorLog(filename, r.body);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not, at the moment you [can't open](https://docs.k6.io/docs/open-filepath-mode) files outside of the init context, and even then they are read-only.

As a workaround, you can use `console.log()` to output the response body and redirect the `stderr` stream to a file.